# Osmosis with Mapsforge plugin on Ubuntu. Am I doing it right?

Tags: openstreetmap

I need to convert an .osm file to a .map in order to test a Mapsforge Android application. Thus, I attempted to install Osmosis on my Ubuntu 12.04 PC. I install osmosis using the debian package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install osmosis
```

After the installation is finished, I download the mapsforge jar file from http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/downloads/list and I copy it to the

```
~/.openstreetmap/osmosis/plugins/
```

folder. However, when I attempt to execute the following command:

```
osmosis --rx file=rethimno.osm --mw file=rethimno.map
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Mar 19, 2013 11:46:27 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.40.1
Mar 19, 2013 11:46:27 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Preparing pipeline.
Mar 19, 2013 11:46:27 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFctory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:72)
at org.mapsforge.map.writer.OSMTagMapping.<init>(OSMTagMapping.java:123)
at org.mapsforge.map.writer.OSMTagMapping.getInstance(OSMTagMapping.java:110)
at org.mapsforge.map.writer.OSMTagMapping.getInstance(OSMTagMapping.java:94)
at org.mapsforge.map.writer.model.MapWriterConfiguration.loadTagMappingFile(MapWriterConfiguration.java:412)
at org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterFactory.createTaskManagerImpl(MapFileWriterFactory.java:53)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.TaskManagerFactory.createTaskManager(TaskManagerFactory.java:60)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.buildTasks(Pipeline.java:50)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.prepare(Pipeline.java:112)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:86)
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:328)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:408)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:351)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
```

Has anyone came across the same problem? If yes, how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are lots of similar XPathFactory error messages on the Internet.

Comment: Well I posted the same question on the Mapsforge issues list and I found the solution. I will post it in order to mark the question as answered. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the instructions posted on
[Mapsforge Issues list](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/issues/detail?id=303)
and I solved the problem.

Comment: Mapsforge have moved to github, the issue mentioned above can be found at https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/issues/303 and this worked for me as well. :)